# Prove that $|f(y)-f(x)|\le f(y-x)$ when $x$ and $y$ are in a vectorspace.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. With the following properties:

$f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)$,

$f(ax)=|a|f(x)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and

$f(x)\ge 0$.

Now I'm trying to prove that $|f(y)-f(x)|\le f(y-x)$.

I  could say that $f(x)+|f(y)-f(x)| =|f(x)|+ |f(y)-f(x)|\ge f(y)$ so then

$|f(y)-f(x)|\ge f(y)-f(x)$, but this is the opposite direction I'm trying to go. I want $\le$ not $\ge$...

I'm now sure how I can show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(-x)=|-1|f(x)=f(x)$. Further, $f(y)\leq f(y-x)+f(x)=f(x-y)+f(x)$ and $f(x)\leq f(y)+f(x-y)$ implying $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq f(x-y)$

Comment: $f(y-x)=|-1|f(x-y)=f(x-y)$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The $x$ here is generic.